# Ubuntu black screen after logging in

Tags: login, screen

I have Ubuntu downloaded on my Macbook laptop (A1181). I have had no issues with the OS beforehand besides slow boot times. Recently after putting in my login information, pressing enter, all I see is a black screen. 5 minutes, 10 minutes, nothing has happened. Help? I know nothing about Ubuntu, please ELI5